# Apache Ignite Cassandra eviction

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, ignite

I'm wondering about Ignite cache eviction in Apache Cassandra.
Is it possible to evict cache entries into the cassandra (like offhaep/file eviction).
As I've understood from the documentation (https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/ignite-with-apache-cassandra) current cassandra intergration is more about read/write through persistence store. But what about cassandra eviction. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries are evicted to swap space, not persistent store: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/off-heap-memory#swap-space

You can implement your own Cassandra based implementation of `SwapSpaceSpi` and use it to evict data to Cassandra.